# How to play audio file in application background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, audio-streaming

In my application, I have to play audio file in application background as long as its running. And I have detailed my process as below,

I have tableview and when I click the particular cell in that tableview then its loads web page. This webpage contains number of audio file link, After clicked the particular link then I need to play that corresponding audio in my application background as long as my application is running and No need to show any player, list and all.

Note: I am using earlier version of iOS 4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you read about the OpenAL framework? It is originally meant to play background music in games and I don't know how much you can custumize it for audio streaming (what i suppose is what you want?). Else you can always use the Audio Toolbox framework, start the music in a background thread and hide the player.

Answer (score 0):

The audio is not played in background even if set all the required parameters while running on simulator, run on device it'll work perfectley by setting UIBackgroundModes to audio in info.plist and AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayBack